# How do I create any regular polygon using turtle?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-turtle

So I have an assignment that asked me to draw any regular polygon using Turtle and I created the code. It works but my mentor said to try again. I would like to know what I did wrong, Thank you!

The requirements for this assignment are:

- The program should take in input from the user.
- The program should have a function that:

  - takes in the number of sides as a parameter.
  - calculates the angle
  - uses the appropriate angle to draw the polygon

```
from turtle import Turtle

turtle = Turtle()
  
side = int(input("Enter the number of the sides: "))
    
def poly():
    for i in range(side):
        turtle.forward(100)
        turtle.right(360 / side)
        
        
poly()
```

Comment: I think you may have only tested this for a 4-sided regular polygon :)

Comment: "takes in the number of sides as a parameter" - nope.

Comment: How many sides does YOUR polygon have? :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the function I used to draw a polygon using Turtle:

Draws an n-sided polygon of a given length. t is a turtle.

```
def polygon(t, n, length):
angle = 360.0 / n
polyline(t, n, length, angle)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be better suited on [math stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

A regular polygon has interior angles `(n−2) × 180 / n`. Theres a good blog post on that [here](https://www.mathsisfun.com/geometry/interior-angles-polygons.html).

You just need to change the angle by which you rotate every time:

```py
from turtle import Turtle

turtle = Turtle()
  
num_sides = int(input("Enter the number of the sides: "))
    
def poly():
    for i in range(num_sides):
        turtle.forward(100)
        # change this bit
        turtle.right((num_sides - 2) * 180 / num_sides)
        
        
poly()
```